# <?php include Stopped Working (It used to work fine)

Tags: php, html

Go figure.

A single php Include worked for several years on my site. Now it suddenly stopped.

\\

```
<?php include('ps_navigator_SOLO_AN_2016_Canvas.html');?>
```

\\

A link to the HTML page (FYI: HTML page is in a subfolder), that contains the above php, suddenly  stopped working. Browsers, instead, tried to Download the page. 
An .htaccess file was updated (apparently) by BlueHost (Apache) recently. I reverted to the previous one that worked.

Now, the link to the HTML page works again, but the php Include on that HTML page doesn't.

The Canvas file that is no longer included in the HTML  works in the folder on its own. So it appears to still be in working order.

The HTML or the div has not changed since the time when it worked.

A PHP Test file works in these folders.

BlueHost Tech Support has told me "Not our problem."

I'd love to hear some ideas on this.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try changing the file to a php file. Hard to diagnose without knowing what they changed, but if that works I'd run with it

Comment: Wesley,
OMG!  That was too easy. I'll try to come up with a tougher one next time.
Thanks so much!